# What is the best way to upgrade Vim 7.2 to 7.3 in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: vim, ubuntu-10.10

I've got default repositories which are pre built with Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to Upgrade Ubuntu to 12.04.

If you can't upgrade the OS, you're gonna have to compile vim from source. Follow the instructions here - [enter link description here](http://www.vim.org/download.php#unix)

You can also try to find another repo, but if you are not allowed to upgrade the OS, I doubt you are allowed to change the repo list...